# Reading data from a bean to JSF inputtext

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, ejb-3.0, facelets

I have a selected bean and I can display its fields using h:outputtext with no problem but this cannot be done by using h:inputtext.

This works fine no problem with it

```
<h:outputText value="Username :"></h:outputText>
<h:outputText value="#{userController.selectedUser.username}" />
```

But this one doesn't work at all! The input text is showing blank.

```
<h:outputText value="Username :"></h:outputText>
<h:inputText value="#{userController.selectedUser.username}" />
```

What am I missing here? Has anyone experienced such a problem?

Will appreciate any help.
Cheers...

(primefaces 3.5, mojarra 2.1, ejb 3.1, jsf 2.1, netbeans 7.2, glassfish 3.2)

Comment: No. An SSCCE which you've also actually executed yourself would be helpful. I bet a simple typo or that you aren't running the code you think you're running.

Comment: No there is not any typo, I tried it many times and with p:inputText as well but no luck. It works fine with outputtext but won't work with inputtext. Thanks

Comment: Yes, PrimeFaces 3.5-Snapshot and this code is in between p:dialog tags. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i could come up with. I dont really know what can be cause. If you use another bean does it work? Does it work if you change the position of the tag, maybe directly under body? If not does it work if you strip everything else?

If something works compare rendered source. I like to use winmerge for that. Good luck

Comment: Thanks Karl, I got it working. I tried it with different beans and realised that inputText triggers getSelectedItem method 2 times, when it triggers it at first time the selectedItem is not set yet so it is null and it cause runtime exception. When selectedItem is null I send a new Item object so I won't let exception occur and it can call getSelectedItem for the second time. It is weird thatwith outputText there is no problem it calls getSelectedItem method just once and the selectedItem is already initialized and so no exception occurs.